# Redis connection reset in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, jedis

I have a class that extends a `RichFlatmapFunction` in my Flink stream job. I create a `Jedis` instance in the `open()` method and close it `(jedis.close())` in the `close()` method, so that all the records that pass through the transformation use the same `Jedis` instance. This approach has not given me any connection errors before. But in a recent job run, I got the error,

> "redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset".

Could this be because I am using the same jedis instance (which remains open) for all the records? I have not set any timeout while creating the instance. So the timeout is also the default value.

Would I be able to avoid this error if I use JedisPool so as to retrieve and close Jedis instances for each record?

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection reset happens where there is any disruption between server and client connection at the network level i.e any Network lost,firewall or application crash or intended close

Also there is a possibility of intended close because of the idle timeout.

Now coming to using JedisPool, Using connection pool is the best practice in multithreaded environments as reusing connections is efficient. So please try to use them with proper configuration

Comment: "By default recent versions of Redis don't close the connection with the client if the client is idle for many seconds: the connection will remain open forever". This is mentioned in Redis's documentation and we are using a recent version of Redis. We have not set 'idle timeout' in the configuration too. So this issue could be because of 'any disruption between server and client connection at the network level i.e any Network lost,firewall or application crash'?

Comment: @avidlearner yes it must be the case for TCP RST input to be triggered